# Get Google Maps HTML to Embed in My Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, google-maps

I have a website where some users enter some data. Address is one of those data. I want to get 
html like this.

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=51.708931,101.425781&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=51.708931,101.425781&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

I want to make some webrequest by entered address and then parse html and get html for embedding. Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JQuery solution o this,ie the user enters address in a text box and address loads up dynamically in a map.

Try [DEMO](http://zhengjia.github.com/address-suggestion/demo/) here and [CODE](https://github.com/zhengjia/address-suggestion/blob/master/demo) here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var map = $('#map').acts_as_map_container();
    // params:
    // container is required
    // suggestion is the element which will contain the suggested address, default to #suggested
    // delay is the delay time for requesting google map api, default to 500ms
    var address = $('#address').acts_as_address({
        container: map,
        suggestion: '#suggestion',
        delay : 500
    });

})
```